# Can I use clear epoxy resin to seal the grout lines?

Tags: bathroom, grout, epoxy, sealer

Can I coat my grout lines in the shower wall with clear epoxy resin to permanently seal them and forget about cleaning yellow stains from mold every now and then?

I am not talking about using epoxy grout, I am talking about just clear epoxy resin on regular grout.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if there would be any lasting adhesion of the epoxy to the grout. And the epoxy itself is subject to yellowing and mildew growth.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using a grout sealer.  It's made for that purpose.